# Initializing a Subclass Instance from a Superclass Object

Tags: python, inheritance, constructor

The documentation for [`logging.Logger`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/logging.html#logger-objects) states:

> Note that Loggers are never instantiated directly, but always through the module-level function logging.getLogger(name)

This leads me to the following question (for which I'll switch to some `Foo` class instead of `logging.Logger`, since I'd like to ask about the principle in general).

---

Suppose there's some class `Foo`, with several attributes and methods:

```
class Foo:
    def method_0(self..):
        ...

    def method_1(self..):
        ...

    def method_n(self..):
        ...
```

I'd like to subclass `Foo`, and specialize only a couple of these methods.

```
class SubFoo(Foo):
    def method_1(self, ...):
        ...
        # Or super - not the point of the question.
        Foo.method_1(self, ...)

    ...
```

The problem is that `Foo` doesn't have a constructor available, only the means to create an object of type `Foo`, say via `getFoo`. The "`Foo`" part of `SubFoo` needs to be an "approved" `Foo` object, and I don't know how to force `SubFoo`s `Foo` part to be made the "approved" object.

**Note**

There are obviously several *workarounds* to subclassing `Foo`, e.g., composition, monkey-patching, clever games with `__dict__`/`gettatr`, etc. Notwithstanding, this question is about subclassing.

Comment: You should use the `__new__` method to construct the subclass before `__init__`. I find https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.subclassing.html#basics-subclassing very usefull.

Answer (score 0):

You have misunderstood inheritance. To create an instance of SubFoo, you just have to instantiate it like you would any other class: `SubFoo()`.

Python doesn't have constructors, and in any case a method not defined on a subclass will automatically inherit the superclass version without you needing to do anything.

Comment: Thanks, but I really don't understand your answer. When I subclass something, the code of my subclass's `__init__` (what I apparently erroneously call ctor) calls the `__init__` of the superclass (either using `super`, or some other way). I don't understand how when I call here `SubFoo`, a `Foo` object will be created (I do understand how to do it via composition, though - I'll just call the equivalent of `getLogger`).

Comment: It wouldn't, a SubFoo would be created. That's the point of inheritance: a SubFoo *is-a* Foo.

Comment: Many thanks, I now understand what you've answered. The point still remains, though, that I'm not creating the subclass instance from a superclass instance, no? Presumably getLogger has some side effects (and if not, my hypothetical getFoo does), so I have to instantiate it with some "approved" superclass object.

Comment: Notwithstanding, thanks for the correction regarding the superclass's init being indistinct to the Liskov is-a. Appreciated.